# How does the structure of the pancreatic acinar cell relates to its function?

Tags: cell-biology, proteins, homework, staining

So the pancreatic acinar cell synthesizes, stores and secretes digestive enzyme precursors called zymogens e.g. pepsinogen.

The structure of the acinar cell shows that there is an apical and basal side. The basal half of the cell is almost entirely filled with rough endoplasmic reticulum which can be shown with pyronin stain showing up pink due to the rRNA of ribosomes. The nucleus is also on the basal side which explains why rER is there too, since the nuclear envelop is connected with the ER membrane. Zymogen granules are on the apical region. Any thoughts as to why there is this polarity in cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The secretion pushes the cell organelles to the basal part.

(although the fat cells have no polarity, their organelles have been pushed to one side of the cell:

[image]

Comparing to adipose cells, the acinar cells secrete their specific proteins on one specific end of the cell, this is why in contrast with fat cells they have well defined polarity.